# Save PubSub stream to a partitioned parquet file in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a spark-streaming application that reads messages from a pubsub topic (e.g. kafka), applies some transformations to each of them, and saves them as a parquet file in GCS, partitioned by an arbitrary column. It's relatively easy to do it using structured streaming and spark-gcs connector.
For example, each message looks like this:

```
{
  "app_id": "app1", 
  "user_id": "u001", 
  "evt_timestamp": 1617105047, 
  "evt_data": { ... }
}
```

I read it as a structured-streaming DataFrame, then partition it by e.g. `app_id` and `user_id`, and then save it to a GCS bucket, which then looks something like this:

```
gs://my-bucket/data/app_id=app1/user_id=u001/XXX.part
gs://my-bucket/data/app_id=app1/user_id=u002/XXX.part
gs://my-bucket/data/app_id=app1/user_id=u003/XXX.part
gs://my-bucket/data/app_id=app2/user_id=u001/XXX.part
...
```

I'd like to move my data processing to GCP, so that I don't have to manage my Spark infrastructure. I could just rewrite my application to use DStreams and run it on Dataproc, but important people are reluctant about using Spark.
I haven't been able to find a way to partition my data. BigQuery supports clustering, which seems to be what I need, but I still need to continuously save it to GCS. Can it be easily done in GCP, or is my use case somehow broken?

### EDIT:

As suggested by the accepted answer, I managed to achieve this using `writeDynamic` and my implementation of `FileIO.Write.FileNaming`.
It roughly looks like this:

```java
PCollection<String> pubsubMessages = ... // read json string messages from pubsub
PCollection<ParsedMessage> messages = pubsubMessages
    .apply(ParDo.of(new ParseMessage())) // convert json pubsub message to a java bean
    .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(2))));

FileIO.Write<Partition, JsonMessage> writer = FileIO.<Partition, JsonMessage>writeDynamic()
    .by(jsonMessage -> new Partition(/* some jsonMessage fields */))
    .via(
        Contextful.fn(JsonMessage::toRecord), // convert message to Sink type, in this case GenericRecord
        ParquetIO.sink(OUT_SCHEMA)) // create a parquet sink
    .withNaming(part -> new PartitionFileName(/* file name based on `part` fields */))
    .withDestinationCoder(AvroCoder.of(Partition.class, Partition.SCHEMA))
    .withNumShards(1)
    .to("output");
```

PartitionFileName can look like this

```java
class PartFileName implements FileIO.Write.FileNaming {
  private final String[] partNames;
  private final Serializable[] partValues;


  public PartFileName(String[] partNames, Serializable[] partValues) {
    this.partNames = partNames;
    this.partValues = partValues;
  }

  @Override
  public String getFilename(
      BoundedWindow window,
      PaneInfo pane,
      int numShards,
      int shardIndex,
      Compression compression) {

    StringBuilder dir = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.partNames.length; i++) {  
       dir
        .append(partNames[i])
        .append("=")
        .append(partValues[i])
        .append("/");
    }

    String fileName = String.format("%d_%d_%d.part", shardIndex, numShards, window.maxTimestamp().getMillis());

    return String.format("%s/%s", dir.toString(), fileName);
  }
}
```

This results in directory structure like

```
output/date=20200301/app_id=1001/0_1_1617727449999.part
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Pubsub with [Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow streaming pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/streaming-pipelines).

Yes, it can do what you want without a lot of effort. You can define windows on your streaming, and use [Parquet IO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/parquet/) to write it to GCS.

Although not Parquet, [this example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-to-gcs) reads from Pubsub and writes text files to GCS.

To reach dynamic file name functionality, FileIO's `writeDynamic` with your own `FilenamePolicy` should work well.

Comment: Apache Beam allows partitioning if a number (and values) of partitions is known in advance. So, partitioning by e.g. app_id and date is not possible. Windowing just splits the incoming data into microbatches based on timestamp.

Comment: You can create your own FilenamePolicy to achieve that. Example: https://gist.github.com/ryanmcdowell/40fe297ebf9576bf9ba14fd6645c82e6

Comment: Which SDK you are using? Found references in Python https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.17.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#dynamic-destinations and Java  https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#writeDynamic--